# Should Service Layer know about Stored procedures and parameters?

Tags: hibernate, spring

We have an application in Hibernate3.6-Spring 3.1.

I have my generic DAO impl like this,( http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html)

```
public abstract class  GenericDaoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>  implements     GenericDao<T, ID>
{

  public int executeSP(final String SP_NAME, Map<String, Object> params)
  {
     SQLQuery sq = getSession().createSQLQuery(SP_NAME);                        
     sq.setProperties(params);       
     return sq.executeUpdate();

   } 
}
```

And this Service Implementation

```
@Transactional
public class PejlAnalysisServiceImpl implements PejlAnalysisService, InitializingBean 
{   
      private CisternDao cisternDao;
      private PejlDataDao pejlDataDao;

      private GenericDao genericDao;  // <--  THIS?

     private void test()
     {
          Map<String, Object> params =  new HashMap<String, Object>();
          params.put("PARAM1",100); //AND THIS
          genericDao.executeSP("MY_STORED_PROCEDURE", params); //And THIS
     }
 }
```

Is this really the right way to do it?

P.S. the stored procedure deal with different database tables so they do not belong to a specific DAO impl.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your design. In one smaller project I wrote, I had a StoredProcedure object that the other components used because a single stored procedure was the one and only way of storing data. I'd recommend avoiding stored procedures in the first place, but if you're stuck with them, you have to decide how integral they are to your design. Are they an essential piece of business logic, or just an implementation detail of your persistence layer?

Comment: They are essential, Ryan, in fact almost core of the application, even though there are only 5 SPs. Lot of calculations happening. And I have no idea why they decided to do it in stored procedure. So yes. I am stuck with it.

Comment: So yeah, I'd say it sounds like knowledge of the SPs in the service layer is appropriate since they're a major part of the app. The one thing you might consider is separating them out from your DAO hierarchy, since, like you said, they don't belong to any one kind of DAO. It might be better to give them their own home, like a "StoredProcedureManager" or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I now implemented my own StoredProcedureManager to handle multiple stored procedures. :-)